# how to pass a parameter (or parameters) to function which is saved inside the .data() method of jquery?

Tags: jquery

i have defined (saved) a function inside the .data() method of jQuery of an object,  to use that function later on in my code.

Problem: how can i pass parameters to that function when i want to call (use) it.

ex:

```
// function declaration

var obj = {};
$(obj).data('callback',function(parameter[s]){
  // do something with parameter
});

// calling the function (usage)

$(obj).data('callback')(parameter[s]);
```

```
var obj = {};
$(obj).data('callback',function(number){
  console.log(number++);
});

$(obj).data('callback')(1);
```

is this that i have written right?

thank you for answering

Comment: can you share your function declaration ?

Comment: yes of course, i will edit the question

Comment: Hello! I think this post have some valuable responses that could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30028331/pass-javascript-function-as-data-attribute-and-execute .

Comment: @OsmanDurdag , i have added the example to the question

Comment: Check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this ?

```
var obj = {};
$(obj).data('callback',function(number){
    console.log(++number);
});
  
// calling the function (usage)
    
$(obj).data('callback')(1);
```

If you want pass array to parameters, you can use like this:

```
var obj = {};
$(obj).data('callback',function(parameter){
    console.log(parameter[3]);
});
  
// calling the function (usage)
    
let array = [1,2,3,4];
    
$(obj).data('callback')(array);
```

Or:

```
var obj = {};
$(obj).data('callback',function(parameter){
    console.log(parameter);
});
  
// calling the function (usage)
    
let array = [1,2,3,4];
    
$(obj).data('callback')(array[2]);
```

Comment: You are welcome. If my answer helped to you, it would be a pleasure for me to you confirm my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you did it correctly you must to change `number++` to `++number` and its better use arrow function same as follow:

```
$(obj).data('callback',(number)=>{
  console.log(number++);
});
```

Comment: thanks mehrzad, can you please tell me why ++number and arrow functions is better to use

Comment: `number++` solved your problem and arrow function is more popular feature in EF6 and i think this link is useful if my answer is useful for you; you makes me happy if you vote me [https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26/]